# How to implement LocatorAutoCreate functionality using EventHandler[]?

Tags: locator, eventhandler

The documentation for LocatorPane says that LocatorPane is a special case of EventHandler, and gives the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
  Deploy@EventHandler[
     Framed@Graphics[Disk[Dynamic[pt]], PlotRange -> 10], 
     "MouseDown" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]), 
     "MouseDragged" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])
  ]
]
```

I want to recreate the LocatorAutoCreate functionality of LocatorPane[] using EventHandler[]. That is, I want to create a graphic in which, when the user presses some key in combination with a mouse press, the mouse position is appended to the list of points being plotted. Here is my first attempt:

```
Dynamic[Deploy@
 EventHandler[
   Framed@ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
   {"MouseDown" :> (pts = Append[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"]])}
 ]
]
```

This causes the mouse position to be appended when a user presses the mouse down.

Here are my two questions that I cannot find the answer to:

1. How do you represent a compound event (e.g. pressing down a key and pressing the mouse down simultaneously) within EventHandler[]?
2. How do you use a key press event when the expression (first argument of EventHandler[]) is a graphics object?

For example, this code works as intended

```
EventHandler[InputField[], {"KeyDown", "x"} :> Print["x has been pressed"]]
```

but the following code does not

```
Dynamic[Deploy@
  EventHandler[Framed@ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
  {"KeyDown","x"} :> (pts = Append[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"]])}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 2}];

Deploy @ EventHandler[
  Framed @ Dynamic @ ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> 1]
, "MouseDown" :> If[
     {"Control"} === CurrentValue@"ModifierKeys"
  ,  AppendTo[pts, CurrentValue[{"MousePosition", "Graphics"}]]
  ]
]
```

Comment: also `If[CurrentValue["ControlKey"], ...]`